# What determines the gender of a Gen-1 Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

Pokémon in the Generation 1 games don't have a gender, but they can be traded to Generation 2 games, where most Pokémon have genders. What determines the gender of a Generation 1 Pokémon when it is traded to a Generation 2 game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Attack IVs.

From the [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gender#Trivia):

> In Generation II, a Pokémon's gender was determined through its Attack IV. Due to this, a female Pokémon could never have a maximized Attack stat (unless they were a member of an all-female species, such as Smoochum), because female Pokémon were given the lower portion of the IV range. This also prevented female Pokémon of a species with a gender ratio of seven males to one female, such as starter Pokémon or Eevee, from being Shiny, due to that also being based partly on the Attack IV.

Basically, females were given the lower half Attack IV range and males the upper.  This [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1y4638/games_how_does_gender_work_in_gen1/) goes into a brief discussion about it as well. I also found [another post](http://pokemon-online.eu/threads/5231/) that explains the ratios:

> 87.5% male ratio: Attack IV needs to be 0 or 1 to be female all others result in a male
>
> 75% female ratio: Attack IV needs to be below 12 to be female
>
> 75% male ratio: Attack IV must be below 4 to be female
>
> 50-50 ratio: Attack IV must be below 8 to be female

Comment: It's worth noting that 100% gender (the Nidorans etc) and 'no gender' (eg Ditto) Pokemon also exist in Gen 1, and when transferred across they will always be that gender.

Comment: How can I tell (from Red/Blue) what a particular Pokémon will end up being when traded?

Comment: From what I understand, its the ratio (above) and the Attack IVs you will need to consider when trading up to Gen 2.  Maybe [this thread](http://serenesforest.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=63781) will help?